# Displaying tooltip on hover on font awesome icon

Tags: html, css, asp.net-core-2.0

I have some font awesome icons on my datatables grid, to replace the text for edit, delete, etc.

Here is how they look

[image: fa display]

Here is the html

```
 <td>
     <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.DutchAuctionTenderId">
         <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
         <span class="tooltip-text">
             Edit Row
         </span>
     </a> |
     <a  asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@item.DutchAuctionTenderId">
         <i class="fa fa-list"></i>
         <span class="tooltip-text">
             Row Details
         </span>
     </a> |
     <a  asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.DutchAuctionTenderId">
         <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>
         <span class="tooltip-text">
             Delete Row
         </span>
     </a>
 </td>
```

I want to show the text in the span, as a tooltip, without using jquery, using css hover when the user hovers over the icons. Is this doable?

I've tried a number of ways, including this last iteration but no text is shown.

```
.tooltip-text {
    width: 145px;
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    background: ghostwhite;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 12px;
    border-radius: 3px; 
    transition: opacity 1s ease-out;
}
.fa {
    font-size: 16px;
    transition: .5s ease-in-out;
}

.fa-fa-trash-o:hover + .tooltip-text, .fa-fa-list:hover + .tooltip-text, .fa-fa-pencil:hover + .tooltip-text {
    display: block;
    color: black;
    animation: fadeIn 2s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to { opacity: 1; }
}  
@keyframes fadeIn {
    from { opacity: 0; }
    to { opacity: 1; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `.fa-fa-trash-o:hover` **remove "-"** after ".fa"

Change that into `.fa.fa-trash-o:hover`

```
.fa.fa-trash-o:hover + .tooltip-text, .fa.fa-list:hover + .tooltip-text, .fa.fa-pencil:hover + .tooltip-text {
    display: block;
    color: black;
    animation: fadeIn 2s;
}
```

Comment: @Vishnu...always need a second set of eyes. How did I not notice that?

Answer (score 3):

why dont u use this way:
add `title` attribute to `i`

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<i class="fa fa-trash-o" title="your tooltip"></i>
```

and style it in this way `i[title]{...}`